# why datagrip connect redis not correct?

Tags: redis, datagrip

When I connect to redis in bash, there is two keys in redis.
[in bash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYvAC.png)
When I connect to redis in Datagrip, there is no keys in redis.
The default db is both 0.
[in Datagrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BcB2O.png)
[in Datagrip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfUFi.png)

How do I connect the right db in datagrip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wrote `keys*;`.

But the semicolon is not a separator in Redis.

As a result, instead of the pattern `*` (meaning "any"), the pattern `*;` is used and nothing is found.

You need to write a clean command: `keys *`.